# Removing x_datadog_kafka_produced header from Kafka produced message

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, datadog

We are using `spring-kafka` library to publish messages on to the kafka topic. We also have datadog to monitor kafka queues.
When publishing a message, `x_datadog_kafka_produced header` gets injected into the message headers and has a binary data which is acting like a poisoned pill for the consumer of the message.

Is there a way to stop this header from getting introduced?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `ConsumerInterceptor` to the Kafka consumer configuration and iterate over the records to remove those headers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, actually in our case the consumers are en external service. Is there something that we can do from the producer side?

Comment: There’s also a producer interceptor.

Answer (score 0):

Another option equivalent to the `ConsumerInterceptor` is to run a Kafka proxy to remove the headers (and more things)—this way, it's agnostic to the language and framework your company uses. Such example [here](https://marketplace.conduktor.io/interceptors/safeguard-message-header-removal/) (i'm working there)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, actually in our case the consumers are en external service. Is there something that we can do from the producer side?

Comment: You can prevent the KafkaProducer to be altered by the DataDog agent, see dd.trace.classes.exclude here https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/trace_collection/library_config/java/
Like DD_TRACE_CLASSES_EXCLUDE="org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer"